# Present continuous "I'm giving you ..." for a gift

Tags: present-continuous

In the first version of Charlie and the Chocolate Factory's movie (1971) there is a moment at the end where Willy Wonka, Charly and his grandfather are in the elevator. Once the elevator is very high in the sky, Willy Wonka says to charly "**I'm giving** the factory to you", Charly is very surprised, he did not know  that Willy Wonka would give him the factory.

My question is why "**giving"** and not "**give**"? Is it because Willy Wonka  had made his decision to give his factory to Charly  before  they got in the elevator (may be a long time before) or did he  want to put some affect and solemnity to this gift or for both reasons. This leads to my second question does present continuous always imply **some affect** when you use it .

Answer (score 1):

It's because Willy Wonka is giving the factory to Charlie at that particular time.  If Wonka were leaving the factory to Charlie in his will, he might write something such as "I hereby give my factory to Charlie."  Present Simple in English is usually a general statement, i.e. I have three kids; I see a bird; I know this; I like this; I go to school five days per week; I wake up every morning, whereas Present Continuous normally talks about something happening in the present and progressing thenceforth, i.e. I'm writing a letter (right now); I'm talking to your mother (right now); I'm doing my homework (right now).  It can also be used to talk about the near future, i.e. I'm going out of town this weekend; I'm not doing anything tomorrow; I'm boating tomorrow.

Regarding your second question, I don't know what you're asking.  The noun "affect" is pretty rare, so I think you mean "effect" instead.  Even with "effect", I still don't understand the second part of the question, however.  Please explain better.

P.S. A mother says to her son,

> "I give you everything and you don't appreciate me."

That's a general statement.

A mother says to her son,

> "I'm giving you everything and you don't appreciate me."

That means that the "giving" is happening now and continuing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67689/discussion-between-nicholas-castagnola-and-user5577).

Comment: In English, when we discuss the summary of stories like Willy Wonka, we would say, "In the story (or tale or conte), Willy Wonka pulls the keys to the factory out of his pocket and gives them to Charlie."  We would say it this way because no action is continuing even for a few seconds into the future; it is a summary of a story; therefore, it's seemingly timeless and instantaneous; hence, no time passes by when discussing the facts of a story.